# VSCode ExtendScript not doing anything V2 (indesign)

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, visual-studio-code

I haven't used ExtendScript for a while. Now I got a new laptop and just updated to the latest indesign-version CC2023. I wanted to debug an indesign-script so I had to set ExtendScript up again. I noticed there is a new version and my launch.json didn't work anymore.

I updated the launch.json to

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "extendscript-debug",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "CC 23 Current Script",
        "script": "${file}",
        "hostAppSpecifier": "indesign-18.064",
        "engineName": "main"
```

But when I launch a script, nothing happens.

The debug menu is not showing anything wrong. It is connected to the CC 23. When I launch the debugging session the "jump, pause etc"-buttons appear for a second and the blue bar at the bottom switches to orange for the same second but nothing happened in indesign. It doens't matter which script I try, it's as if it's not connected to indesign at all. But it also doesn't show any error message.

[image]

Does anybody have an idea whats wrong here?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Can't find any help online after much searching. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I'm sorry, It works now. I don't know why or how.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the parameters in launch.json have changed.  Here's what's working for me using Visual Studio Code 1.81.1 with InDesign 2023 v18.5:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "hostAppSpecifier" : "indesign",
        "engineName": "main",
        "type": "extendscript-debug",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Name of MYSCRIPT",
        "script": "${workspaceFolder}/MYSCRIPT.jsx",
    },
```